How to copy shading maps but still be able to change materials?
I'm creating a little meat man, and I want to have his body use mostly the same shading maps as his head, but with a different texture for me to paint his splotches on for his body. When I copy the nodes over from his head to his body then try to change the texture for me to paint the new splotches on, the texture for the head changes as well. How do I create a new instance of the same nodes so it doesn't change the shading nodes for the head when I change the ones for the body?

Create a new Image Texture node and paint with the head texture on it? Because if you paint the image texture onto itself, you'll alter it of course

I clarified my question with more images, so you can get a better understanding of what I meant.


When I copy the nodes over from his head to his body then try to change the texture for me to paint the new splotches on, the texture for the head changes as well

All we see in your screenshot is one material containing a node group and a material output node.
You do not explain either what you mean by "copy the nodes" (do you make a new empty material and copy-paste nodes there, or apply the same material to both objects, or ...?).
We do not know what you mean by "change the texture", we don't even see the "texture" in your material.
It's a bit hard to tell exactly what's going on and how to do things if you don't give enough information. But we can explain some principles:

Blender, like any other software, stores different types of data, with each different types of information and ways to interact with each other.
Data is shared. In many ways, you can have the same data used in many places. Which can be a huge save in time and resources. But understanding what are the different levels of data and how they interact with each other is important to correctly use it.
Materials are a data block, which contains Nodes and their inputs. Hence, if you can have one Material applied to different object, any change in that material's nodes their inputs will impact all the objects on which that material is applied. Conversely, if you want similar materials across objects but with slight differences, you might want to make individual copies of the material instead of just calling the same material over.
Node Groups are also another data block. Nodes and their inputs inside a Node Group are stored in the Node Group data block, so they propagate in any instance of that Node Group in any material.
Images are another data-block, which (among other things) can be called in an Image Texture node. Any change made to a specific texture will be propagated in any place where you call that texture.

Since we don't know how your Node group is made inside nor what is your "texture", I can only assume you may or may not have an image texture somewhere inside your Node Group. In which case:
If you need a different texture for the body, not only you need to create a new Image data block, but also a new Raw Meat Node Group data block to load that different Image, and also a new Material data block to use the Raw Meat Node group that uses the new texture.
Which brings to a question: are you using the Node Group correctly? Usually, Node Groups are made to be handles from outside, at the Material's level. If you need a texture, usually you are meant to plug it to the Node Group's inputs in the material, not enter inside the Node Group itself. Partly because of how data sharing makes reusage increasingly tedious the lower you go.
So two options: revise how you use the node group in the first place, or do everything the hard way.
Revising
Again, hard to say without seeing the node group and how it works insisde and how you use a texture in there. But a wild guess would be that somewhere inside there's an image texture you painted, and is plugged to some parameters that are also exposed in the node group's inputs. If so, unplug that image texture without breaking the existing connections, bring that image texture node to the material level, and plug it to the node group's inputs.
Then, all you have to do to reuse that in the body is:

Assign the same material to the body
On the body, press this icon to make a duplicate of the material:

Press the same duplicate button in the Image texture node
Paint the newly created texture as you wish.

Advantage of this is that it's easier to reuse the data, which is quicker for you, but also for rendering, and uses less memory.
The hard way

Assign the same material to the body
On the body, press this icon to make a duplicate of the material:

Press the same duplicate button in the Group Node
Enter inside the Group Node
Press the same duplicate button in the Image texture node
Paint the newly created texture as you wish.

